# python request.get does form the right url

Tags: python, html, get, python-requests

I tried to use python requests sending GET requests. However, I found the url that formed by request.get() doesn't follow the document.

Here is an example:

```
import requests

root_web_address = 'http://www.amazon.com'
action_address = '/s/ref=nb_sb_noss'

get_url = root_web_address + action_address

input_1_value_unicode = unicode('search-alias=aps', 'utf-8')
input_2_value_unicode = unicode('asics', 'utf-8')

get_parameters = {'url':input_1_value_unicode, 'field-keywords':input_2_value_unicode}

r = requests.get(get_url, params = get_parameters)

print r.url
```

The expected URL should be:

```
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=asics
```

However, the print r.url gives me:

```
http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aasics
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requests.get` here is actually 301 redirect. And the `url` property of the response object contains the last redirected url, hence the url being printed.

For intermediate url you can do -

```
print r.history[0].url
```

And for the url used while sending the request, you should do -

```
print r.request.url
```

Check the following documentation for more info -

1. [Requests QuickStart](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)
2. [requests.Response.url](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.url)
3. [requests.Response.history](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.history)
4. [requests.request.url](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request)